# (ungetc(getc(in), in) != EOF) means ..?

Tags: c

Looking through some old code that is not mine, I ran into this line:

```
if (ungetc(getc(in), in) != EOF)
```

Where `in` is a file pointer.

I'm unfamiliar with these functions and their use.

Am I interpreting this correctly as if (the end of the file has **not** yet been reached) ?

Comment: Re “I'm unfamiliar with these functions and their use”: Did you look them up, in the C standard or elsewhere?

Comment: The first step to understand a function is to look it up in the documentation, for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc). Please note that [a certain amount of research is expected before asking a question on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/12149471).

Comment: Yes, I looked them up (hence my interpretation) and yes I was still unsure.

Comment: It is [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It "peeks" at the stream `in` looking for EOF, without removing the character from the buffer. Or rather it grabs a character then puts it back.

> Am I interpreting this correctly as if (the end of the file has not yet been reached) ?

Yes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is correct. `feof` won't tell you if there is any data left, it only tells you that *after* you've already tried to read past the end of file. This check guarantees at least one character available to read.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah you are correct. I removed the part about feof since it just added confusion anyway.

Comment: It is important to know that `ungetc(EOF, in)` does not push anything back to the stream `in` but returns `EOF`.